# Extend URL with input field text

Tags: javascript

basically what I'm trying to achieve should be quit simple, but my skills are limited. In the end I want to create a `'fake'` search bar on my website. It's an input field which should go to the URL

```
mysite.com/search?q=INPUT
```

As this is another sites search field and the `'INPUT'` should be the input from my site. This way I can have `'fake'` search bar for another page.

Hope this makes sense.

If you take a look at this code, can we from here?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
function gotoURL(){
  var newURL = document.GotoForm.theURL.value
  document.location.href=newURL
  }
</SCRIPT></HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM ACTION="JavaScript:gotoURL()" 
      METHOD="GET" 
      NAME="GotoForm">
URL:
<INPUT   TYPE="text" 
          NAME="theURL"  
          SIZE="50" 
          VALUE="INPUT TXT"
     MAXLENGTH="100">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" 
      VALUE="Goto">
</FORM></HTML>
```

And how can  manage special characters?
(space = +) (? = %3F)

Best, T

Comment: use  encodeURIComponent  , ex:-var newURL = encodeURIComponent(document.GotoForm.theURL.value)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your function as below :

```
function gotoURL(){
  var newURL = encodeURIComponent(document.GotoForm.theURL.value);
  document.location.href= 'http://testsite.com/search?q='+newURL
}
```

> The encodeURIComponent() function encodes a URI component. This
>   function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the
>   following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

Comment: @Thalys You don't have to worry about the spaces. They'll get encoded as %20, similar to other special characters, and be decoded just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like charm.
@Ouroborus Thanks for the tip too, I didn't realized it's basic encoding :)